# How do I pass a call back to angular resource save method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement angular resource for login like this

```
 var data = new Login({               

            username: user.userName,
            password: user.password
       }) 
 data.$save()
```

This is suppose to return some data to me if login is successful or return error if it is not.

What I want is the callback like the angular http post method like this .

```
    data = JSON.stringify({
            username: user.userName,
            password: user.password
                      })
    $http.post('API/sigin',data,

            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }

 )
   .success(
       function(response){

     // success callback

      console.log("doing sign in");

     }, 
       function(error){


       // failure callback

      return error


      }
        )
```

I switched to resource when http post failed me. It will just just hang perpetually and will later return error.

I am using angular 1.4.3.

any help, info will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..factory.js

```
//Create a factory for the Login API
angular.module(...)
.factory('LoginEntity', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        'API/sigin',
        {
            save: {method: 'POST'},
            update: {method: 'PUT'}
        }
    );
}])
```

...controller.js

```
angular.module(...)
       .controller('xxxController', ['LoginEntity', function(LoginEntity){
    //in Controller add LoginEntity dependency

    LoginEntity.save({
                            username: user.userName,
                            password: user.password
                        },
                        function (response) {
                            //success callback
                        },
                        function () {
                            //error callback
                            //usually do some logging stuff here
                        });

}]);
```

Comment: Thank you, It seems to be logging in when I pass a state to the success callback but when I ask it to return the response it hangs perpetually

Comment: @ huan feng  Again What do you mean by LoggerService? do you mean to say LoginEntity.error?

Comment: you can ignore the LoggerService line, i wrote it there because usually we do some logging when the api call has some error.

Comment: what you mean pass a state to the success callback, how did you write the code?

Comment: I mean a redirect state provider to the application page for authenticated user. e.g  $state.go('app'); But I want it to return the response as the API responds with the information of logged in user. ok, for the loggerService, I have already replace that with my own custom error message

Comment: It seems this is another question? I still can not understand your question before i saw what you have written in the success callback

Comment: it's not another question, I simply wrote return response in the successback

Comment: It worked, I logged the response in the console and I saw all the return value . Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much, Please I have another challenge I have been battling with for a while now. I am trying to assign the response from the success call back to a $rootscope variable so it is available to other controllers. I have created another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128058/how-do-i-declare-a-rootscope-in-a-controller-and-access-it-in-another-controlle

Comment: i just saw your last comment, have you question been solved already?