# how do I declare a $rootscope in a controller and access it in another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am implementing an angular resource for a login system like this

..factory.js

```
//Create a factory for the Login API
angular.module(...)
.factory('LoginEntity', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
return $resource(
    'API/sigin',
    {
        save: {method: 'POST'},
        update: {method: 'PUT'}
    }
);
}])
```

...controller.js

```
.controller('xxxController', ['LoginEntity', function(LoginEntity, $rootScope){
//in Controller add LoginEntity dependency
  $rootScope.loggedinuser = {};

LoginEntity.save({
                        username: user.userName,
                        password: user.password
                    },
                    function (response) {
                        //success callback
                      $rootScope.loggedinuser = response;
                    },
                    function () {
                        //error callback

                    });

}]);
```

...AppCtrl

```
.controller('AppCtrl',function($scope,$rootScope){

   username = $rootScope.loggedinuser.username;

  }
```

That is what I have but the rootscope does not seem to be accesible in the App controller.

Any help, or assistance will be highly appreciated

Comment: looks like you are accessing `$rootScope.loggedinuser` before the success callback is executed (assuming the error callback produces some console log so you know that the success one was executed). have a look at [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Just like @Aprillion said, you are accessing $rootScope.loggedinuser before the success callback is executed. You can move the API call to AppCtrl instead of xxxController, and do logic in the sucess callback.

Comment: Thanks @huan feng , I moved it to the App Ctrl and it works fine

Comment: @huan feng, sorry for my troubles, I was to trying to equally store it in a local storage like this    window.localstorage['loggedInUser'] = JSON.stringify(loggedInUser);    
                                        
                     $scope.loggedInUser = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['loggedInUser'] || '{}');

Comment: but it kept saying cannot set property loggedinUser of undefined . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

your controller.js has a error, add the `$rootScope` to your code like this:

```
.controller('xxxController', ['LoginEntity', '$rootScope', function(LoginEntity, $rootScope){
//in Controller add LoginEntity dependency
  $rootScope.loggedinuser = {};

LoginEntity.save({
                        username: user.userName,
                        password: user.password
                    },
                    function (response) {
                        //success callback
                      $rootScope.loggedinuser = response;
                    },
                    function () {
                        //error callback

                    });

}]);
```

Comment: it's still not working ....Cannot read property 'loggedinuser' of undefined in the AppCtrl

Comment: what do you get the result of response?

Comment: Cannot read property 'loggedinuser' of undefined in the AppCtrl

Comment: can u debug your code and watch the value of response?

Comment: what's the value of response?

Comment: response is suppose to be like {userId: 1234, username: 'theusername', anotherVariable: 'anotherparameter' }

Comment: do you read from the $rootScope in AppCtrl before the response is received?

Comment: @kplus this sounds like you might have a typo e.g. `rootScope` instead of `$rootScope`... or missing dependency injection strings in `.controller('AppCtrl',function($scope,$rootScope){` which should be `.controller('AppCtrl',["$scope", "$rootScope", function($scope,$rootScope){`

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
.controller('xxxController', ['LoginEntity', '$rootScope', function(LoginEntity, $rootScope){
///
}]);
```

...AppCtrl

```
.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope, '$rootScope', function($scope,$rootScope){
///
  }]
```

Comment: it's still not working ....Cannot read property 'loggedinuser' of undefined in the AppCtrl

Answer (score 0):

use dependency injection. this should hopefully work:

```
.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope,$rootScope){

   username = $rootScope.loggedinuser.username;

}])
```

This makes also sure that on minification, the behaviour does not break, wenn the variable names are automatically changed.

Comment: it's still not working ....Cannot read property 'loggedinuser' of undefined in the AppCtrl

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject $rootScope to your controller

```
.controller('xxxController', ['LoginEntity', '$rootScope', function(LoginEntity, $rootScope){
// TO DO Something
}]);
```

Or Implicit Annotation (careful to minify your code)

```
.controller('xxxController', function(LoginEntity, $rootScope){
// TO DO Something
});
```

Here is the link https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 0):

inject $rootScope in controller

```
.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope,$rootScope){

   $rootScope.loggedinuser = "your user detail"

}])
```

Comment: it's still not working ....Cannot read property 'loggedinuser' of undefined in the AppCtrl

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted. If you want to persist the loggedinuser in localStorage, you should do it in success callback.

```
...AppCtrl
.controller('AppCtrl', ['LoginEntity', '$scope', '$rootScope', function(LoginEntity, $scope,$rootScope){

    LoginEntity.save({
                    username: user.userName,
                    password: user.password
                },
                function (response) {
                    //success callback
                    localStorage.setItem('loggedinuser', JSON.stringify(response));
                },
                function () {
                    //error callback
                    LoggerService.error('Landing page:error during LoadTestEntity initiation');
                });

  }
```

Comment: Thanks, If i retrieve it like this     $scope.loggedInUser = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['loggedInUser'] || '{}'); I could access it access it within the login scope, but it returns undefined outside the scope, is there something I am getting wrong?